# Slot not being called after signal emitted in QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Why isn't my slot `sl_classASaveDataFromClassB` in `ClassA` being called? I am emitting a signal to the slot from another class (`ClassB`) and expect that the function `sl_classASaveDataFromClassB` is called when the `ClassB::closeEvent` function is called.

The flow of events is as follows:

1. On program launch, ClassA constructor is called which sets up the signal/slot connection: `connect(ClassB::getInstance(), SIGNAL(&ClassB::sig_ClassBData(float,float)), this, SLOT(sl_classASaveDataFromClassB(float,float)));` where I connect ClassB's signal to ClassA's SLOT function.
2. user presented with general config screen. The code for this screen contains a struct with config variables.
3. User clicks an button which launches a window where they enter two float values relating to float two values (`blahA` & `blahB`).
4. User selects "Save" icon which calls `ClassB::on_btnDataSave_clicked()`
5. This invokes the `closeEvent` QT function `ClassB::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)` which emits the signal `sig_classBData`

Placing breakpoints in the code shows that the overidden `ClassB::closeEvent` is called on window close, and the signal is emitted, however the slot function is never called.

ClassA.c

```
ClassA_UI::ClassA_UI(QWidget *parent, c_Instrument *Instrument) :
    QFrame(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ClassA_UI)
{
        connect(ClassB::getInstance(), SIGNAL(&ClassB::sig_ClassBData(float,float)), this, SLOT(&sl_classASaveDataFromClassB(float,float)));
}

void ClassA_UI::on_btnClick_setVals()
{
    ClassB::getInstance()->show();
}

void ClassA_UI sl_classASaveDataFromClassB(float latitude, float longitude)
{
    qDebug() << "test";
}
```

ClassA.h

```
class ClassA_UI : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ClassA_UI(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ClassA_UI();
public slots:
     sl_classASaveDataFromClassB(float blahA, float blahB)
}



ClassB* ClassB::getInstance()
{
    if(instance == nullptr){
        instance = new ClassB();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

ClassB.c

```
ClassB* ClassB::instance = nullptr;

ClassB::ClassB(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ClassB)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    data = new data;

    connect(this, SIGNAL(sig_ClassBUpdateBox(QString, QString)), this, SLOT(sl_GeoLocationUpdateBox(QString,QString)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

void ClassB::on_btnDataSave_clicked()
{
    // save long lat values here

    location->blahA = ui->lineEdit_blahA->text().toFloat();
    location->blahB = ui->lineEdit_blahB->text().toFloat();

    // Values set successfully
    emit sig_ClassBUpdateBox( "Location Updated", "Location update applied.");
    this->close();

}

void ClassB::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "closeEvent" ;
    emit sig_classBData(data->blahA, data->blahB);

    event->accept();
}
```

ClassB.h

```
namespace Ui {
class ClassB;
}

class ClassB : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ClassB(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ClassB();

private:
    Ui::ClassB *ui;
private:
    typedef struct  {
        float blahA;
        float blahB;
    } data;

    data *location;

    static ClassB* instance;
public:
    static ClassB* getInstance();
signals:
    void sig_ClassBUpdateBox(QString Title, QString Message);
    void sig_classBData(float blahA, float blahB);

};
```

Comment: Typo: `SLOT(&sl_classBSaveData(float,float))` --> `SLOT(sl_classBSaveData(float,float))` -- i.e. lose the '&'.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for pointing that out. I've made the change, but the slot is still not being called.

Comment: I'd recommend using the modern connect syntax as it avoids silent typo errors https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax. If you must use the clunky old syntax then you'll need to keep an eye on your applications console output as it'll normally print an error on invalid connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by modifying the connection string to the following:

```
connect(ClassA::getInstance(), SIGNAL(sig_ClassBData(float,float)), this, SLOT(sl_classASaveDataFromClassB(float,float)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

I'll share my findings for anyone that also runs into a similar issue.

So the `connect` function actually returns a boolean `true`/`false` for the connection. In my constructor I added a temp boolean variable that I placed a breakpoint at, and that showed me the connection was returning `false` which indicated to me that the reason why the slot in `classA` was not being called was because the connection was never successfully set up.

From the documentation, the connect string is as follows:

```
QObject::connect(const QObject *sender, const char *signal, const QObject *receiver, const char *method, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)
```

Breaking that down:

```
// Send class
const QObject *sender = w_sfmGeoLocConfiguration::getInstance(), 
const char *signal = SIGNAL(sig_GeoLocationData(float,float)), 

// Recieve class
const QObject *receiver = this,
const char *method = SLOT(sl_updateGeoLocation(float,float)), 
Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::QueuedConnection
```

Comment: you really should try the "new" (its actually over 10 years old now) connect syntax, its much less error prone https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax